# Why is none of my Mac memory compressed?

Tags: macos, memory, compression

I am constantly up against the 16GB physical memory barrier on my mac.  I have looked in Activity Monitor and ZERO memory is compressed.  I would like to have OS/X be aggressive in compressing - how to configure it?

[image]

**Update** I found some info on seeing what the compression value is set to:

```
$sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode
vm.compressor_mode: 4
```

The value of 4 would indicate that compression *is* enabled.  But then .. why no compression is happening?

Comment: There’s virtually no memory pressure. Why do you want it to compress?

Comment: I noticed that too.  The mac has come to a screeching halt. Why does it not understand that *I NEED MEMORY* - and thus increase the pressure? The symptoms? I can not run any more programs or even open gui windows.  I have been reaching 99.X% physical memory consistently recently.

Comment: Yosemite tries hard to always keep RAM full - the new paradigm, empty RAM is wasted RAM. As you are showing no memory pressure & no swap usage, VM set [correctly] to 4, then your slowdown is something else. Check for spurious CPU activity from md worker or mds_store etc

Comment: Ahh, sorry, that's still Mavericks, isn't it? Mavericks is nowhere near as good as Yosemite at handling RAM… & the symptom you're seeing is actually 'unfixable' without going to Yosemite.